# Searching Assignment difficulty... Linked List

Tags: java, search, linked-list

OK so Searching is my weak area in Java and could really use help as to where to begin on this Assignment!!
The data member n is no longer needed.
The LinkedList should be created and assigned to theList in the constructor rather than in run().
makeScanner(), getPerson(), and main() should not be modified. The Person and FileFormatException classes should also not be modified.
display() will no longer compile since theList is no longer an array. You can either change it to use a foreach or simply remove it.
run() has a loop that adds Person objects to the array. Change it so that it adds these to a list instead. Consider:

```
  theList.add(p);
```

The variables index and n are no longer necessary.
Modify search() to perform the linear search on a list rather than an array. The easiest way is to use a foreach and return the correct Person if found. If the correct Person is not found, it should return null as before.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ContactList {

private LinkedList<Person> theList;

private int n;            // the number of Persons in theList
private Scanner keyboard;

public ContactList() {
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
} // no-arg constructor

// Returns a Scanner associated with a specific text-based URL
// online.
private Scanner makeScanner() throws IOException {
final String source = 
  "http://userpages.umbc.edu/~jmartens/courses/is247/hw/05/05.txt";
final URL src = new URL(source);
return new Scanner(src.openStream());
} // makeScanner()


// Return a Person instance based upon data read from the given
// Scanner.
private Person getPerson(final Scanner in) throws FileFormatException {
if (!in.hasNextLine())
  return null;

String line = in.nextLine().trim();
int key = Integer.parseInt(line);
String name = in.nextLine().trim();
String mail = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
if (in.hasNextLine()) {
  String empty = in.nextLine().trim(); // skip blank line
  if (empty.length() > 0)
    throw new FileFormatException("missing blank line");
} // if

return new Person(key, name, mail);
} // getPerson()


// Display the array contents.
private void display() {
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  System.out.println(theList[i]);
} // display()


// Read the Person objects from the web page and then start the user
// interface. 
private void run() throws IOException {
theList = new Person[1024];
try {
  Scanner in = makeScanner();

  int index = 0; 
  Person p = getPerson(in);
  while (p != null) {
    theList[index++] = p;
    p = getPerson(in);
  }
  n = index;
 } catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("Error reading web page: " + e);
  System.exit(1);
  // The call to exit may be overkill, but it is nice to return an
  // error (nonzero) value to the environment. Since main() does
  // nothing after run() returns, simply returning to main() would
  // be acceptable also. Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to
  // simply move the call to ui() below into the try block. Then if
  // an exception is thrown, the UI never executes.
} // catch

// Run the user interface.
  ui();
//    display();
} // run()

// Loop prompting the user for an integer key. Terminate on a negative
// key. If a record matching the key is found, display the
// record. Otherwise, indicate that no matching record was found.
private void ui() {
int key = getKey();
while (key >= 0) {
  Person p = search(key);
  if (p == null)
    System.out.println("No person matching key " 
                       + key
                       + " found.");
  else
    System.out.println(p);
  key = getKey();
 } // while not done
} // ui()

private int getKey() {
System.out.print("\nPlease enter a key: ");
int key = keyboard.nextInt();
return key;
} // getKey()

private Person search(final int key) {
for (int index = 0; index < n; ++index)
  if (key == theList[index].getId())    // Is this the right one?
    return theList[index];

return null;      // apparently the requested object is not present
} // search()

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
ContactList cl = new ContactList();
cl.run();
} // main()

} // class ContactList
```

Comment: Do you understand conceptually how a LinkedList works? If not that's a good place to start.

Comment: what is your question? Is all this code really needed for the concrete question?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would do is change your list declaration! (like you said)

change:

```
private Person[] theList;
```

to

```
private LinkedList<Person> theList;
```

Then use your compiler to print all your compilation errors or look at all the red squiggles produced in your ide.

At each point where there is a compilation error or red squiggle, determine what array operation you are attempting. Then search on this page for the correct operation or sequence of operations that are equivalent. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Useforeachlooptogothroughelementsinalinkedlist.htm

This is an example of using a for each statement to link through a simple list.  You should change your declaration from an array to a linked list and try something similar to the for each in the above example.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html
More reading on the subject if you need a little more background.